# Android preferences set manually are not loaded in settings activity

Tags: java, android

I want to seed my app's default preferences from a build variable, so I cannot use the XML-based preference defaults.

In my `MainActivity`, I have this method:

```java
/**
  * Set the default values programmatically
  */
protected void initPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    if (sharedPref.getString("elasticsearch_url", "").equals("")) {
        editor.putString("elasticsearch_url", Env.elasticsearchTestUrl);
    }
    if (sharedPref.getString("elasticsearch_user", "").equals("")) {
        editor.putString("elasticsearch_user", Env.elasticsearchTestUser);
    }
    if (sharedPref.getString("elasticsearch_password", "").equals("")) {
        editor.putString("elasticsearch_password", Env.elasticsearchTestPassword);
    }
    if (sharedPref.getString("elasticsearch_index", "").equals("")) {
        editor.putString("elasticsearch_index", Env.elasticsearchTestIndex);
    }
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "Settings: " + sharedPref.getAll());
}
```

I call this within `onCreate` directly after the app starts. The log shows the settings being saved fine.

Now, I have a second activity, an automatically-generated `SettingsActivity`, which looks like this:

```java
package com.aveq.testandroidpacketcapture;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SettingsActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting preferences from XML resource ...");
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I start this activity via:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

the settings activity opens, but the values there are empty:

[image]

The XML based on which the preferences are loaded looks like this:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="Elasticsearch">

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="elasticsearch_url"
            app:title="Elasticsearch URL"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="elasticsearch_user"
            app:title="Elasticsearch username"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="elasticsearch_password"
            app:title="Elasticsearch password"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="elasticsearch_index"
            app:title="Elasticsearch index"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
  </PreferenceScreen>
```

As far as I can tell, all the keys match up. When I log the shared preferences in the `onCreate` method of the settings activity, they are correct, so why are my values not loaded?

Comment: IIRC using preference screen does not get/save them in `MODE_PRIVATE` and you need to get them from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a PreferenceScreen the SharedPreferences get saved to default shared preferences so you need to grab them from there with this

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

vs pulling them from private context

```
getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```